# File listing by using find, sort and ls commands

Tags: linux, terminal, find, ls

How can i see files bigger than 10MB sorted by their size and in descending order in my home directory, by using find sort and ls commands (terminal)?

I begin my pipe with this command:

```
find ~ -type f -size +10M
```

and then i continue with sort:

```
|sort -rh
```

But when I include the `ls` command, everything goes off.
Note: I want a printed result like this:

```
 rw-r--r--+  1 user users  100M May 18  2021 file.tar.gz
 rw-r--r--+  1 user users  99M May 18  2021 file2.tar.gz
 etc
```

Comment: How did you include the ls command ?

Comment: How about `find ~ -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +10M -ls | sort -n -k 7`?

Comment: If you pipe to `xargs ls -l` you should get what you want.

Comment: Please post the complete command instead of describing what you did.

Comment: I used "find ~ -type f -size +10M | sort -rh | ls -lh". The problem is that with this approach, it does not print files bigger than 10MB as an output. Example:

Comment: xargs ls -l as g00se said. I also included the h parameter and we are fine! So now we have this pipe: find ~ -type f -size +10M | sort -rh | xargs ls -lh and we can see this result:                                                                                                                                 
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 17M Nov 23 16:04 (file path).                                             
Thanks everyone for the assistance, that was really helpful.

Comment: Sorry - forgot about the reverse bit ;)